# Sprites coordinates are not changing when rotating around a point

Tags: swift

For example if i have a sprite of a planet with a moon orbiting it, the moons coordinates don't change. So how to update the moons coordinates, when it rotates around the earth?

Comment: We need to see your code.  You need to make an attempt before we can help you solve the issue.

Comment: Calculate the new position with the angle and the moon's distance from the center of the image

Answer (score 0):

You probably added `Moon` as child of `Earth` and then started rotating `Earth`, right?

In this case the position of `Moon` in relation to `Earth` doesn't change. And since the position of every `SKNode` is expressed in relation to it's parent, `Moon`'s `position` property will stay the same.

In the image below `Moon`'s is `(0, 100)`.

[image]

Not let's rotate `Earth` of 45°.

[image]

Now the position of `Moon` is still `(0, 100)` because it is expressed in relation to `Earth`.